# Program not running when put through pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm having a problem with pyinstaller when I use `exit`, an error appears and the program cannot run. When I use `quit` or `sys.exit()`, the program does not run. If I leave all of these out and use the X button, the threads keep running in the task manager. What function should I use to fix this?
Needed Code

```
def exitgame():
    sys.exit()
    
main = Tk()
main.title("Fruit Clicker")
main.geometry("400x350+300+100")
Button(main, text="Play", command=rootopen).pack()
Button(main, text="Quit Game", command=exitgame).pack()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing function to quit a application, you can close application directly without a function, just replace "command=exitgame" to "command=main.destroy" for 'Quit game button'.

Sample code-

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
main = Tk()
main.title("Fruit Clicker")
main.geometry("400x350+300+100")
Button(main, text="Quit Game", command=main.destroy).pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: this is what gets returned: ```_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed```

Comment: @AnonymousPupper2006 I have updated my answer with sample code, try it and let me know